# how to compute a value based on input from 3 dropdown lists?

Tags: javascript, php

I have three dropdown lists having 6,3,3 options in them respectively. I need to compute a value depending on the combination of values chosen from the dropdown lists.I have 54 different values for 54 different permutations and combinations for the dropdown menus. Please suggest an optimized way of achieving this in php.

```
enter code here
 <select name="designation" id="desg">
  <option value="1">International Doctor</option>
  <option value="2">Domestic Doctor</option>
  <option value="3">MBBS STUDENT</option>
  <option value="4">nursers </option>
  <option value="5">Postgraduates / Interns</option>
  <option value="6">Faculty</option>
</select>
<select name="workshop" id="wshop">

    <option value="None">None</option>

    <option value="workshop1">workshop1:PACET</option>

    <option value="workshop2">workshop2:PEMC</option>

    <option value="workshop3">workshop3:Research Workshop</option>

   </select>
   <select name="category" id="cat">


    <option value="None">None</option>

    <option value="1">1</option>

    <option value="2">2</option>

    <option value="3">3</option> 
    </select>
```

if a user select his designation,category,workshop the corresponding amount should be displayed 
[picture contain a table with corresponding amount for different workshops,desginations,category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqDbR.jpg)

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on the question. Please, take a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please share some code and what you have tried.

Comment: You will have to create change events on all of them and based on selected value, you will have to compute result

Comment: Who up-voted this question? This question shows zero effort or research, and provides not nearly enough detail for anyone to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: Click "edit" under your question, paste the code you have so far, save your question (we need to see the code for those dropdowns).

Comment: Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: i have added my piece of code,please go through it and suggest me

Answer (score 1):

The Question is not very clear to me, but I am going to show an example which may help you.

This code may be similar to your code for this web page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mapping={'13':'Bob','14':'Alice','23':'foo','24':'bar'}
    function displayMapping(){
        var e1=document.getElementById('l1')
        var e2=document.getElementById('l2')
        var key=e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value+e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML =mapping[key];
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="l1" id='l1' onchange="displayMapping()">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="l2" id='l2' onchange="displayMapping()">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <p name="sum" id='sum'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

You may create an assosiative array for your permutations (In this example array named `mapping`), then you can create a function which will automatically called when there will any change in your dropdown lists (In this case that function is `displayMapping()`).

This example uses `javascript` hence reflected in **local machine**, If you want to calculate in **server side** then it may not be very useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

may be use like that

selectName[]
selectName2[]

etc.

Comment: I see in your profile that you a very new, so, you have to know that your answer looks like a comment because it's too short. Enrich your answer by including more code (valid code), for example, how to use JavaScript to access one dropdown, and, how to do the same with PHP. Otherwise your "answser" might be downvoted.